# can we send a flat file to IBM MQ or we have to create a string representation of the flat file so that it can be send as a message

Tags: java, string, ibm-mq, flat-file, mq

I do not have a Flat file which could be converted to string directly. Instead I have a Java object which I need to send as a Flat File  to MQ.

Comment: Using JMS?  You can send serialized objects,  but i think it may be a IBM MQ classes for JMS feature.

Comment: What is the consumer application expecting? a file or message?

Comment: consumer application is expecting a Flat File and yes I am using JMS to send the messages to MQ

Comment: Can the consuming app accept serialized objects?

Comment: Yes it can , consumer app has to write the implementation based on the message type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IBM MQ with JMS](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/)

There are following options, you can use to send your java class data into MQ queue.

[TextMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html) - can send any kind of text data, i.e. you can serialize your java object to XML using JAXB (or JAX-WS in case of SOAP), or JSON using something like GSON, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind), JSONP (Resteasy,Jersey in case of REST etc) or even CSV

[ObjectMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html) - can send java [serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) objects, please note - [this is risky](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3275924/oracle-plans-to-dump-risky-java-serialization.html)

[BytesMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html) - can send any kind of data (including any kind of text format). I.e. you can serialize your java objects into some binary format like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or some ASN.1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a ToString method on your object, or convert into  XML or JSON, which will serialise.

So for example if you use JSON, your receiving app can deserialise the flattened string into JSON, then an appropriate Java Object

The sending app -

```java
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;


JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("xxx", yourJavaObject.somepropertyormethod);
obj.put("yyy", yourJavaObject.someotherpropertyormethod);

String msgAsAString = obj.toString();
```